# GKE ingress health checks fail for backend instance groups(Nodeport)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm facing below issue while deploying GKE LB (ingress) on GCP

Health check fails with below error (checked logs)
resource 'projects/abc_project/global/backendServices/k8s-ingress-svc-acct-permission-check-probe' was not found

I have my services yaml as :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zone-printer-deployment
  namespace: abc
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zone-printer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zone-printer
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: zone-printer
        image: region-docker.pkg.dev/abc_project/abc/zone-printer:0.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zone-printer-service
  namespace: abc
spec:
  type: NodePort 
  selector:
    app: zone-printer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9000 
    targetPort: 8080
```

and my ingress_yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
kind: Ingress 
metadata :
  name : abc-ingress 
  namespace : abc
  annotations:
     networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: ssl-redirect
     kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: static_ip
spec :
  tls :
  - secretName: abcsecrets 
  rules :
  - http :   
      paths :
      - path : /hello 
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend :
          service:
            name: hello-service 
            port:
              number: 8000 
      - path : /zone-printer 
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend :
          service:
            name: zone-printer-service 
            port:
              number: 9000
```

XLB gets deployed , but all my backends have failed health checks even after allowing all nodeports ports(30K-32767) in firewall , as well as these local ports.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Have you tried the [required firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#firewall_rules) for health check?